# Enterprise 1.14.2.0: Problem with understanding getProductsReadonly function

Tags: category, ee-1.14.2.0

My Task was enabling Position field on category product selection grid some how position box was hidden category product selection grid.

In the debug process i find out there is a function

```
$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
```

which is responsible for enable editable text field but i could not found any **getProductsReadonly** or **setProductsReadonly** also i could not found any attribute **products_readonly**.

**Question1** : Is anyone can help me to understand definition for **getProductsReadonly** ?

Function always return null.

So in my case this solution wasn't work because there is some embedded css called in phtml(app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/merchandiser/smartmerch/tab.phtml) file

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('merchandiser')->isHideProductPositionField()): ?>
    <style>#catalog_category_products_table tbody tr td.editable .input-text { visibility:hidden; }</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am sure that this file isn't changed and it came form magento.

**Question2** : Is this right way to call embedded css by magento team ? I mean they can override or use **getProductsReadonly** function rather then hide text box by css.